# preciso de relacionamento Um para muitos entre 3 tabelas

Tags: python, django

Olá tenho a tabela Pessoas, Veiculos e Mensalistas que são os usuarios que pagam por mes o estaionamento preciso que cada pessoa possa ter mais de um veiculo, mas ao cadastrar na tabela mensalista ao selecionar uma pessoaa aparecam no outros ampo somente os carros que ela possua, como está agora, está aparecendo todos os carros de todo mundo.

Sou bem iniciante e preciso de explicações detalhadas, agradeço a ajuda e a paciencia

Models.py

```
TATE_CHOICES = (
('AC', 'Acre'), ('AL', 'Alagoas'), ('AP', 'Amapá'),
('AM', 'Amazonas'), ('BA', 'Bahia'), ('CE', 'Ceará'),
('DF', 'Distrito Federal'), ('ES', 'Espírito Santo'),
('GO', 'Goiás'), ('MA', 'Maranhão'), ('MT', 'Mato Grosso'),
('MS', 'Mato Grosso do Sul'), ('MG', 'Minas Gerais'),
('PA', 'Pará'), ('PB', 'Paraíba'), ('PR', 'Paraná'),
('PE', 'Pernambuco'), ('PI', 'Piauí'), ('RJ', 'Rio de Janeiro'),
('RN', 'Rio Grande do Norte'), ('RS', 'Rio Grande do Sul'),
('RO', 'Rondônia'), ('RR', 'Roraima'), ('SC', 'Santa Catarina'),
('SP', 'São Paulo'), ('SE', 'Sergipe'), ('TO', 'Tocantins')
)


class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, blank=False)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.nome) + ' - ' + str(self.email) 


class Veiculo(models.Model):
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    ano = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    placa = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    proprietario = models.ForeignKey(
        Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, )
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)


def __str__(self):
    return self.modelo + ' - ' + self.placa
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def mensalista_novo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MensalistaForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('core_lista_mensalista')
    else:
        form = MensalistaForm
    return render(request, 'core/lista_mensalistas.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Vc precisa deixar mais claro a sua duvida, vc se refere ao backend ou ao front? Esta parecendo que se refer ao frontend, se sim coloque a tela p vermos, aponte os campos nos quais vc quer o resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que percebi , neste momento esta tentar relacionar duas tabelas numa relação de N-N ou seja , uma pessoa pode ter vários carros , e um carro pode ter varias pessoas, para uma melhor estrutura de base de dados , precisa de uma tabela a parte onde tem a chave estrangeira para a pessoa e outra para o carro . E para a sua duvida , onde no dropdown do carro aparece consoante a pessoa que se escolhe , aconselho a ler esta tutorial , pode ajudar.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html